# Variables undefined when compiling bootstrap 2.3.2 using dotless

Tags: less, dotless

I'm using dotless to compile an older version of Boostrap (2.3.2)

my main.less file looks like this

```
@import "less/variables.less";

.bootstrap {
    @import url("less/bootstrap.less");
    @import url("less/responsive.less");
}
```

When compiling it i get the error

> .box-sizing is undefined on line 158 in file 'mixins.less': [157]:
>   min-height: @inputHeight; // Make inputs at least the height of their
>   button counterpart (base  line-height + padding + border) [158]:
>   .box-sizing(border-box); // Makes inputs behave like true block-level
>   elements
>          --^ [159]: } [Done - Failed]

But if I do this it works,

```
@import "less/variables.less";

.bootstrap {
    background-color: @white
}
```

Any ideas of whats wrong?

Thanks

== EDIT ==

It seems to be the enclosing of .boostrap that is the issue, when simply having

```
@import url("bootstrap.less");
@import url("responsive.less");
```

in my main.less everything works fine

Comment: .bootstrap {} creates a new scope, see: http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope

Answer (score 0):

consider:

```
mixin() {
@color: red;
}

p {
color: @color;
}
```

outputs:

`NameError: variable @color is undefined`

but:

```
.mixin() {
@color: red;
}

p {
.mixin();
color: @color;
}
```

outputs:

```
p {
  color: red;
}
```

the `.mixin` call leaks @color inside the scope of `p`, see also: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using winless (http://winless.org/) instead of dotless, didn't need to change anything in my less definition.